# Why is XSLX file getting downloaded as XLS in IE only?

Tags: excel, google-chrome, internet-explorer, xlsx

We created an XLSX file using Excel 2013 (packaged it within the WAR file) and gave a hyperlink to this file for users to download it. Application is hosted in Tomcat server.

Users using IE 11, when downloading this file, it is getting downloaded & saved as .XLS extension.

Users using Chrome, when downloading this file,it is XLSX extension.

It is a direct download hyperlink to the file. ***Why is it behaving differently in both browsers ? What could be the root cause of this issue ?***

Answer (score 2):

We were having the same problem - `.xlsx` files were only downloading as `.xls` and causing annoying warnings for the users when they tried to open the file, because it was opening the file as an `.xls` so the contents did not match the format, but it worked fine in Chrome.

We found that had two entries for the `.xlsx MIME Type` in `IIS`:

**application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet**

and

**application/vnd.ms-excel**

When we removed the second one (`vnd.ms-excel`), the file downloaded appropriately and we were able to open the document directly without the error message.

It appears that the second mime-type entry caused Internet Explorer to treat all excel files as `.xlsx`. Now, *why* it does that, I'd love to know.

Hope this helps.

Comment: we do not have IIS but, i will check if such a config exists in our Websphere environment. Thank you.